# Novell Groupwise 7 SMTP Setting

Tags: smtp, novell

Our Groupwise server currently uses an outbound SMTP server for all outgoing mail not within our domain. Is it possible to force Groupwise to use the SMTP server for ALL mail including addresses within the domain?

Comment: What version of Groupwise?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to do this. AntiVirus systems that support GroupWise need to run on the Mailbox server so they can deal with messages directly. Using an external appliance for monitoring of all email is not supported. The only point an external appliance can monitor emails is the interface between GroupWise and external non-GW systems.